# why do people choose SnapLogic over informatica for cloud integration?

Tags: cloud, integration, informatica, snaplogic

We are looking for a good cloud integration tool. we have informatica cloud and SnapLogic as an option, but still looking for more information what key features differentiate these two tools? people are choosing SnapLogic over informatica these days. What are the main features that SnapLogic provides but not informatica or viceversa?

Answer (score 6):

Background:  The world of data is changing very rapidly - there's an explosion in data volume, variety, velocity, and location.  According to Gartner, this is causing the world of application and data integrations to collide.  The erstwhile clear demarcation between nightly batch (ETL) and real-time (EAI) integrations is fast disappearing.  Customers need a platform that can straddle both these use cases in a single platform.  Traditional integration products are unable to keep up with this new world. SnapLogic refers to this as the "Integrator's Dilemma"

Here are some relevant technical readings that will help you understand your needs better and help prioritize them in your decision-making.  Good luck!

http://www.snaplogic.com/blogtechnical-advantages-of-json-centric-ipaas/

http://www.snaplogic.com/blogcloud-integration-chalk-talk/

Disclaimer: I am currently employed by SnapLogic. I have spent many years in the integration industry and am trying to respond to help you in your decision-making with the best of my abilities.

Comment: Here's a detailed technical overview of the product.  Hope this helps in your decision-making as well - http://bit.ly/NcWPTr

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure where you are getting the data to make such a statement but SnapLogic did win a bunch of awards this year:
https://www.snaplogic.com/about-us/recognition

I would suggest first to understand your requirement and then search for the right cloud integration tool.

Why restrict yourself just to SnapLogic and Informatica Cloud. There are other companies in this space, as well.

Most of these companies offer free trials and have a responsive sales team.

You could learn more about SnapLogic on their website and their blog contains demo videos:
http://www.snaplogic.com/blog/

Answer (score 0):

Basically SnapLogic is a iPaas Tool (Integration Platforma as a Service), One of the growing online cloud based ETL and integration tool.

- As per the Gartner report one of leader in "Enterprise Integration
  Platform as a Service" refer below link

  https://www.snaplogic.com/press-releases/gartner-names-snaplogic-as-a-leader-in-the-magic-quadrant
- When compare with Informatica SnapLogic cost is somewhat low and also
  SnapLogic recently introduced Auto scaling of EMR cluster especially 
  for Spark mode pipelines.
- Easy to use and have more connectors snaps for different categories
  like flat files, ERP ,CRM, IOT , Alexa, Databases , Cloud includes Google 
  cloud, Azure and AWS.
- Easily manageable of projects and users and groups etc.